# RenderTable function behaving unusually in loop

Tags: r, shiny

See the code below - what *should* happen is, when you press the button, it displays table1 and table2, but what actually happens is you get table2 twice.

It works correctly if you write out both statements without the loop, but this isn't an option for my actual app. Have also tried isolate(i) (even though it's not reactive).

How can I get this to work?

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tableOutput("test1"),
  tableOutput("test2"),
  actionButton("button", "Press me!")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  tables <- list(table1 = data.frame(a = 1:4, b = 1:4), table2 = data.frame(c = 5:8, d = 5:8))
  
  observeEvent(input$button, {
    for(i in 1:2) {
      output[[paste0("test", i)]] <- renderTable(tables[[paste0("table", i)]])
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're a victim of R's lazy evaulation.  `for` evaluates lazily, so when the outputs are rendered, `i` is `2` for both outputs.  `lapply` forces evaluation, so this gives you what you want:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tableOutput("test1"),
  tableOutput("test2"),
  actionButton("button", "Press me!")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  tables <- list(table1 = data.frame(a = 1:4, b = 1:4), table2 = data.frame(c = 5:8, d = 5:8))
  
  observeEvent(input$button, {
    lapply(
      1:2,
      function(i) output[[paste0("test", i)]] <- renderTable(tables[[paste0("table", i)]])
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Thank you for taking the effort to produce an appropriate MWE.  Not many do.

**EDIT**

Another option, which is longer but perhaps more transparent and adaptable, is simply to reference the button within the renderer for each table:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tableOutput("test1"),
  tableOutput("test2"),
  actionButton("button", "Press me!")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  tables <- list(table1 = data.frame(a = 1:4, b = 1:4), table2 = data.frame(c = 5:8, d = 5:8))
  
  output$test1 <- renderTable({
    if (input$button > 0) {
      tables$table1
    }
  })
  
  output$test2 <- renderTable({
    if (input$button > 0) {
      tables$table2
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```